# Entity Framework Constructor Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this segment of code selecting **one** column from a table which works fine:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select Col1 from ....).ToList();
```

However, as expected when trying to select more than one column it errors as the result structure is incorrect.

I've tried the following:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<Tuple<string, string>>("select Col1, Col2 from ...).ToList();
```

Which returns the error:

> The result type 'System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.

How can I fix this, Am I correct to be using Tuple?

Comment: How about using a class (with the properties you select in the query) instead of Tuple?

Comment: try string[] just a guess.... dont think it would work... class is much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a class for your query result e.g.

```
class QueryResult
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
}
```

and query like this:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<QueryResult>("select Col1, Col2 from ...).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! This has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a class that contains properties that have the same name of your columns in order for `Database.SqlQuery` to work. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx).

```
public class MyType
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
}

List<MyType> list = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyType>("select Col1, Col2 from ....").ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah, I think the more important thing is you have to make sure the properties have the same name with your query columns.